# Georeferencing using QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

[image]

I georeferenced two maps for project. Points that were referenced are now stuck on my main project and I don't know how to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

The points disappear automatically when you close the Georeferencer dialog window. Before that, you have the option to either save the Ground Control Points (GCP) or discard them.